# Why do I get the syntax error "file not found" in Razor MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code:

```
@section ftr_scripts {
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

Under the following:

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js
```

I get a long green syntax error line with a message saying "file not found". Is this to be expected or am I just calling that javascript in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the http

```
@section ftr_scripts {
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks pretty obvious to me now :-)